# Tree Graph Layout Algorithm

Tags: graph, jung, gephi, graph-layout

I have an acyclic graph - a tree.

Each node of the graph will have some attributes that I need to show in a glyph.

Let's us say the size of each Glyph is 100x100 pixels.

I am looking for an algorithm that is fast and efficient for up to 100,000 nodes that will lay out the nodes in xy space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUNG has a few different layout algorithms for trees that should work fine: TreeLayout, obviously, but you might also look at RadialTreeLayout and BalloonLayout.

http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/layout/package-summary.html